# Executar código apenas uma vez

Tags: php

Pensem o seguinte , estou criando um código "363636". Com esse código, estou dando a opção do cliente digitar no input. Porém, eu quero que esse código seja executado apenas uma vez. Ou seja, quando ele digitar o código no input, acabou!. Caso ele passe esse código para outra pessoa utilizar esse script não seja mais aceito. O código que eu fiz foi o seguinte.

Criei um variável chamada $prenchimento, com o código do cupom.

```
$preenchimento = "363636";  // CUPOM
```

Logo, criei outra variável chamada cupom, onde recebe a variável preenchimento

```
$cupom = $preenchimento // NÃO MEXER
```

No formulário, eu estou pegando as informações via $_POST. Ou seja, quando o cliente digita o cupom ele faz a verificação via if. Sempre verificando se o valor digital corresponde com a variável $cupom :

```
    if($tipodeinscricao == $cupom) { 

     echo "Cupom Validade";
}else{

     echo "Cupom não validado";
}
```

A viarável $tipodeinscricao é o que está sendo pego do cliente via $_POST. Como eu já disse, eu preciso que o cliente utilize esse código apenas um vez, como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Você precisa guardar esse valor em algum lugar para verificar se já foi digitado. Pode ser um banco de dados, um cookie, uma session, por exemplo... sendo que estes dois últimos não dão garantia de segurança... por exemplo, o cookie pode ser apagado, a session pode ser expirada ao fechar o site...

Comment: Não existem outra forma ?

Comment: Se quiser guardar o valor permanentemente, só com banco de dados. O cookie tb funciona, mas se o cara entender disso, pode apagar ele fácil.

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer com o cookie ?

Comment: Ah, vc pode criar um arquivo no servidor e guardar informações nele.

Comment: Para utilizar cookies, utilize a função **[setcookies](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php)**, mas no seu caso o ideal é banco de dados, exemplo **[SQLite](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sqlite-open.php)**.

Comment: O cookie não daria certo, porque se for usar o código em outro navegador seria validado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que usar banco de dados (que seria mais recomendado) não é uma opção, e usar *cookie* não seria bom porque o *cookie* só é válido no navegador que o criou, além de poder ser apagado, você pode usar um arquivo de texto para guardar a informação no servidor e fazer a verificação.

O arquivo guardará o código digitado, e você poderá verificar se esse código existe dentro do arquivo.

Crie um arquivo de texto, por exemplo `codigos_usados.txt` (só um exemplo de nome) no seu servidor. Em seguida, insira o código enviado pelo cliente (cada código enviado será inserido em uma nova linha dentro do arquivo). O código todo ficaria assim:

```
<?php
// essa parte do código no $_POST você disse que já tem
$tipodeinscricao = $_POST['nome_do_campo'];

$preenchimento = "363636";  // CUPOM
$cupom = $preenchimento; // NÃO MEXER

$nome_arquivo = 'codigos_usados.txt'; // nome do arquivo de texto

$valido = false; // crio um flag

if($tipodeinscricao == $cupom) { 

    // aqui eu verifico se o código existe no arquivo
    $arq = file_get_contents($nome_arquivo);

    // o IF abaixo retorna false se o código não existir no arquivo
    if( !preg_match('/'.$tipodeinscricao.'/',$arq) ) {

        // aqui eu gravo o código no arquivo
        $fp = fopen($nome_arquivo,"a");
        $codigo = $tipodeinscricao.PHP_EOL;
        fwrite($fp, $codigo);
        fclose($fp);

        $valido = true; // valido a flag

    }
}

if($valido){
    echo "Cupom Validado";
}else{
    echo "Cupom não validado ou já usado";
}
?>
```

Comment: Olá!!!!, Desculpe a demora, irei verificar e lhe respondo !

Comment: Olá!, Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente mestre !

Comment: @EuSouNoob Legal!

Comment: Tenho apenas uma dúvida. Por exemplo, caso eu queira utilizar mais de um cupom, eu poderia usar um array ? $preenchimento = array("363636","2020", "5050") , ou isso poderia não funcionar ?

Comment: @EuSouNoob Tem como. Basta vc puxar o código que quer dentro da array. Mas cuidado, os códigos precisam ter um padrão. Por exemplo, se tiver "363636" e vc colocar outro código "6363" vai achar os dois.

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado pela ajuda